# Can I install Overwatch and play WoW at the same time

Tags: world-of-warcraft, overwatch, battle.net

I just started installing Overwatch. I would like to play World of Warcraft while I wait for it to install. Will it install while I play World of Warcraft?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To prevent the download from pausing while you're playing WoW, do the following in the Blizzard App

- Click the Blizzard icon near the upper-left corner.
- Click Settings
- Click Game Install/Update on the left side.
- Uncheck "Pause updates when I launch a game." You may need to scroll down to see this option.
- Click the Done button in the lower-right.